# "[T]he assignment statement $X=X+1$ makes no sense [...] in mathematics." Why not?

Tags: formal-languages, programming

Taken from *Programming Languages and Principles*, Chapter 1, by Tucker and Noonan:

> ... the assignment statement
>
> $X = X + 1$
>
> makes no sense either in functional programming or in mathematics.

Why does it make no sense in mathematics?

Comment: because assignment and comparison are different concepts. This is the reason the programming languages use two different symbols (= and == usually). In mathematics, = is comparison, while usually in programming = is assignment

Comment: In Pascal, assignment was written `x:=x+1`. You’ll see that notation sometimes used in math. In math, $X=X+1$ is like the programming Boolean statement, `X == X+1`, which can be said to make sense - it is a valid statement - but in almost all contexts is false. (You need work hard to manufacture a context where it is true - say, in C++ where `X` is an object and `+` is (re-)defined.)

Comment: Not so much work.  You only need a value which represents numerical infinity.  Standard (IEEE 754) floating-point arithmetic contains such values, and many other languages have integral types with infinite values.  (For example, in Python `from math import inf; inf == inf + 1` is true.)

Answer (score 8):

Context matters.

In the context of mathematics, the equation "$X=X+1$" means "$X$ equals $X+1$", which is false (for example, substitution of $X=0$ gives $0=1$; substitution of $X=1$ gives $1=2$; and that's more than enough to see the falsity with crystal clarity).

In the context of programming languages, the assignment operator "$X=X+1$" means "take the numerical value stored in the memory position tagged $X$, copy that value into the arithmetic processor, add $1$ to the value in the arithmetic processor, and then copy the value in the arithmetic processor back into the memory position tagged $X$".

As you can see, these are incompatible meanings.

Comment: So we need two operators, one for assignment and one for the test for equality?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the comment of @Exodd.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that such a statement makes no sense in mathematics. If $X$ is finite, it is a bit more justifiable. However, in the setting of (transfinite) cardinal arithmetic, if we have $X=\aleph_0$, then $X=X+1$ is certainly true. In fact, more than that is true:
$$\aleph_\alpha + \aleph_\beta = \max(\aleph_\alpha,\aleph_\beta) \text{ for } \alpha,\beta\in\mathrm{Ord},$$
where $\mathrm{Ord}$ denotes the class of all ordinals.

Such a statement is true, in a sense, in (transfinite) ordinal arithmetic. For example, $\alpha + 1 \neq \alpha$ for $\alpha\in\mathrm{Ord}$. However, some care is still needed as $1 + \omega = \omega$.